# Laravel orderBy not sorting data in correct order

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have a `buildings` table with column named `building_number`. This could possess values like `1, 2, 10, A, B`. Now I want to order it as follows:

```
1
2
10
A
B
```

And I have tried code as follows:

```
$res = \DB::table('buildings')
       ->where('property_id',$id)
       ->orderByRaw('CAST(building_number as UNSIGNED)') 
       ->orderBy('building_number','asc')
       ->pluck('building_number');
```

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
            [2] => 1
            [3] => 2
            [4] => 10
        )
)
```

If I removed `->orderByRaw('CAST(building_number as UNSIGNED)')` this line, the order of the result will be:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 2
            [3] => A
            [4] => B
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this result because your `building_number` column in your table is of the type `varchar`

which contains all `letters` and `numbers` so it looks at the **first character in each string and sorts it**

To solve this you can try alphanumeric sorting.

```
$res = \DB::table('buildings')
            ->where('property_id',$id)
            ->orderByRaw('LENGTH(building_number)','asc')
            ->orderBy('building_number','asc')
            ->pluck('building_number');
```

**OR**

you can query data without order by then use this.

```
$sorted = $res->sortBy('building_number');
```

Comment: with your answer it throws `Unknown column 'LENGTH(building_number)' in 'order clause'`. However, if I try with `orderByRaw` it returns result in order `1,2,A,B,10`

Comment: okay. Try this: `$sorted = $res->sortBy('building_number');` you can query data without order by then use this.

Comment: I had already found this answer, whats wrong with this is that it returns result in unorderd index and if I tried with `->values()->all()` It turns object to array. And with array I could not used `->groupBy()` later on this result. So, is there any way that could return result with correct index as well?